# Sql: IFERROR formula : checking and adding 228, single quote and comma

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this formula

```
=IFERROR(IF(FIND(228,A1,1)=1,A1&","), "228"&A1&",")
```

A1 has either 99991234 or 22899991234.

The end result i want is, If there is already 228 before the number, formula should ignore 228 and add 'xxxxx',

```
'22899991234',
```

If there is no 228 before the number in A1 cell, formula should add '228xxxx',

```
'22899991234',
```

But for the formula i have, the result i am getting is

```
22899991234,
```

Its not adding the single quotes before and after the number. please correct the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add single quotes into the strings.

```
=IFERROR(IF(FIND(228,A1,1)=1,"'"&A1&"',"), "'228"&A1&"',")
```